# How can I Show a API output number in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, currency, quotes

See I want to make an HTML file that will display the current USD-GBP,

I am using this site: currencylayer.com
Their api :
http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=YOU_KEY_HERE&currencies=BBP&source=USD&format=1

Gives Me this output:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms",
  "privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy",
  "timestamp":1522395543,
  "source":"USD",
  "quotes":{
    "USDGBP":0.71
  }
}
```

I Need an HTML file that Just displays 0.71.
Thank You In Advance

Comment: I've tried to check youtube and StackOverflow for examples, but they don't work for me.

Comment: If you are able to retrieve remote data with api, you should als be able to get a value from an object.. Is that a PHP or JS object? Please post the code you are using to fetch data

Comment: http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=6396cd29244983062e55d5398ff2486a&currencies=ZAR&source=USD&format=1

Comment: @GNY I added answer, hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse` to get the value(s) that you're looking for:

```js
var myQuote = '{"success":true,"terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms","privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy","timestamp":1522395543,"source":"USD","quotes":{"USDGBP":0.71}}';

var jsonData = JSON.parse(myQuote);
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = jsonData.quotes.USDGBP;
```

```html
<div id="quote"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "success":true,
  "terms":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/terms",
  "privacy":"https:\/\/currencylayer.com\/privacy",
  "timestamp":1522395543,
  "source":"USD",
  "quotes":{
    "USDGBP":0.71
  }
};

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = jsonObj.quotes.USDGBP;
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```